# My regex for testing phone issue

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate these phone number formats:

```
517123123
+48517123123
+48 517 123 123

(48)517123123
(48)517 123 123

517-123-123
48 517-123-123
48/517-123-123

48 517 123 123
```

I wrote this regex:
`(\+?)+(((\(([0-9]+){2,2}\)))|(([0-9]+){2,2})?)+(\/?)+(\s?)+(([0-9]+){9,9}|([0-9]+){3,3}(\s|-){1,1}([0-9]+){3,3}(\s|-){1,1}([0-9]+){3,3})`

The problem is that it's makes big numbers like `8978978979878978967` valid. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Instead of validating phone numbers, why not just remove all non-numeric characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you lost anchors.... however, use my regex `^(\+?(\(\d{2}\)|(\d{2})|(\d{2}[/ ])))?((\d{3} \d{3} \d{3})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})|(\d{9}))$`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at just the end of the regex, I see something that you seem to be doing in multiple places;

```
([0-9]+){3,3}
```

The `+` says at least one repeat of [0-9], which makes `1111111111111` a perfectly valid match. You then limit it to exactly 3 of those matches, which can still be a very long number.
If you want exactly 3 digits, remove the `+`.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I can't see what your regex is doing, there is too much superfluous stuff in it.

1. You have too many groups
2. You want to repeat optional characters!?

   e.g.:

   - `(\+?)+`, you don't need a group around and you don't want to repeat that, so `\+?` is what you want here.
   - `(\s?)+`, do you want to say "0 or more whitespaces"? Then `\s*` is what you need.
3. When you write  e.g. `{9,9}`, then you can remove one digit, `{9}` is the same.
4. You are nesting quantifiers, **thats the place where you allow too many characters**. You have multiple places, where you do `([0-9]+){9,9}`, that means 1 or more digits and repeat that 9 times.